# Make a list from same transaction number

Tags: list, bigdata

We have a big dataframe that contains different transactions and one of column is a transaction number(rq_id). I want to put all the columns that have the same transaction number in one list How can this be done?
[sample of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsLsg.jpg)

Make all the columns that have the same transaction number in one list How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

To group data from a DataFrame based on a common transaction number (rq_id) and put all the columns with the same transaction number into one list, you can use the Python pandas library. Here's how you can do it:

Assuming you have a DataFrame named df, and you want to group the data by the 'rq_id' column, you can use the groupby function and apply to create lists for each group. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'rq_id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'col2': ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'W', 'V']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Group the data by 'rq_id' and collect each group's data into a list
grouped = df.groupby('rq_id').apply(lambda x: x.drop('rq_id', axis=1).values.tolist())

print(grouped)
```

In this example, grouped will be a pandas Series where each entry contains a list of values from the corresponding group with the same 'rq_id'. The 'rq_id' column is dropped using x.drop('rq_id', axis=1) before converting the data to a list to get a list of lists.

Please adjust this code to match your actual DataFrame and column names. The resulting grouped Series will contain lists of data associated with the same 'rq_id'.